# SIP messages are not visible after Phone rooting(samsung A33)

Tags: android, sip, telephony

I am trying to get the sip messages in the rooted samsung a33.I took the tcpdump and still no sip packets can seen. Anyone can help here.

Took the tcpdump from phone side using PCapdroid and also tcp dump inside adb shell. But not getting any sip messages.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding the encrypted keys(run :ip xfrm state to get the keys) to the Wireshark in ESP protocol and you able to see the SIP messages.